# How to store selection and span to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a select list which has three different options.

When a user selects a city, I'd like show a price span based on the selected option.

I am also trying to save selected option in localStorage, so if you refresh page, the selection stays selected and the right price span stays visible.

This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>


<span id="related_ny_price">New York price</span>

<span id="related_london_price">London price</span>

<span id="related_paris_price">Paris price</span>
```

**JS**

```
    $('[id^="related"]').not(':first').hide();

    $("#city").on('change', function() {

--------------------------------------------        

$("#related_"+this.value+"_price").show().siblings('[id^="related"]').hide();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var item = window.localStorage.getItem('city');
        $('select[name=city]').val(item);

        $('select[name=city]').change(function() {
           window.localStorage.setItem('city', $(this).val());
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no element with name `citya` in DOM. Second you try to get the value of 
`paikkakunta` that doesn't exist in localstorage object. You have to get the city the way you set it.

**html**

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>
<span id="related_ny_price">New York price</span>

<span id="related_london_price">London price</span>

<span id="related_paris_price">Paris price</span>
```

**js**

```
$('[id^="related"]').not(':first').hide();

$("#city").on('change', function() {
  $("#related_" + this.value + "_content").show().siblings('[id^="related"]').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  //get city
  var item = localStorage.getItem('city');
  $('select[name=city]').val(item);

  //change the selector. There is no element with name citya in DOM
  $('select[name=city]').change(function() {
    //set city
    localStorage.setItem('city', $(this).val());
  });

});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o9mjdnss/)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed those typos. Also **#related_" + this.value + "_content** should be **#related_"+this.value+"_price** Now it stores the selection, but is shows first span when refreshed.